# TYPO3 8 <f:image width and height not working

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x, fluid-images

I'm trying to resize my image but isn't working.

```
<f:image src="{shoe.imageOne.uid}" width="400c" height="525c" treatIdAsReference="1" alt="{shoe.name}" />
```

I saw on the documentation and other places and this should work but isn't. The image still uses the original size 600x800.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the install tool if image procession with ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick works properly?

Comment: Yes it does work properly.

Comment: Your syntax is valid and it _should_ work, check your IM is working once again, also don't forget to clear all caches.